# Yii 2 Namespace missing?

Tags: php, yii

I have a namespace missing problem in Yii 2. I installed the advanced application. I am referencing a backend model from my frontend controller. Below is a code snippet of my backend model, frontend controller and error message.

**Error**

> Unable to find 'backend\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions' in file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\jobmanager/backend/models/PaymentsMethod/TermsAndConditions.php. Namespace missing?

**Backend Model**

```
namespace app\models\PaymentsMethod;
use Yii;

class TermsAndConditions extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
```

**Frontend Model**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new estimate();
    $tnc   = new \backend\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved my problem. I was trying to access a backend model class from a frontend controller. I resolved this by moving the backend model class to the common folder and from there I can reference it from both the backend and frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your frontend, first include the namespace and then instantiate:

```
use app\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions;
$tnc =  new TermsAndConditions();
```

OR

As alfallouji said you can directly use:

```
$tnc =  new \app\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing from **frontend** then use *frontend* instead of **app**

i.e

```
namespace frontend\models\PaymentsMethod;
```

and if you are accessing from **backend** then use as below

```
namespace backend\models\PaymentsMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the model using this namespace `app\models\PaymentsMethod` and then you are trying to instantiate `\backend\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions`.

You should be doing that in your frontend model :

```
$tnc =  new \app\models\PaymentsMethod\TermsAndConditions();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Each tier in the advanced app in Yii2 has its own root alias. For example, the front-end tier has a root alias @frontend, while the back-end tier root alias is @backend. So in each tier `\app\` references to either @frontend or @backend. In your cash i will be call @frontend but I want to call @backend. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

123456789101112

```
<?php

 namespace app\controllers;
 use yii\web\Controller;
 use app\models\users;
  class UserController extends Controller{
 public function actionIndex()
 {
echo "working on .....";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace "backend" for "app" only models search

ex: app\models\PaymentsMethod;